# List posts by IDs using native Wordpress search

Tags: php, wordpress

I have stored a list of WordPress post IDs in a PHP variable, and I want to display a list of posts to the user on the native WordPress search results page using that list. I want to use Wordpress default search for re-use my search template.

I have tried adding query_args to the query like:

https://mywebsite.com/?s=2482,2511,880,884

But I haven't achieved the desired result. Is it possible to do this? How can it be done? I haven't found clear documentation on this matter.